# Using time.sleep() in komodo edit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, komodo, komodoedit

I am trying to make a simple program in komodo edit using python that when it runs will print out 10 seconds worth of time in the command output.

The code is as follows:

```
import time

seconds = 0

while seconds != 10:
    time.sleep(1)
    seconds += 1
    print(">", seconds)
```

When I run this in komodo edit, it doesn't print out the numbers as wanted.

I want the number 1 to be printed after one second of time, the number 2 to be printed after two seconds of time, and etc.

Instead, it prints out all the numbers (1-10) after 10 seconds of time.

I have run this exact same program in the python IDLE and it works as it should, printing one number per second.

What am I doing wrong or what do I not understand/know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program is likely running in an environment where it does not believe its output is connected to a terminal, so `stdout` defaults to block buffering, not line buffering. Since you're outputting very little data, the buffer never fills, and is only flushed just before the program exits.

The simplest fix is to add the `flush=True` argument to your `print` call, so the buffer is explicitly flushed after each `print`:

```
print(">", seconds, flush=True)
```